# _header.html.erb account dropdown function does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the ruby on rails tutorials from http://ruby.railstutorial.org .
The following is the _header.html.erb code, is the same as the tutorials. but the drop down function of account does not work.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more of the application it's hard to determine the exact problem, however based on what you have supplied I can suggest the following:

- refer to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns and ensure you are using the right markup nesting (looks like you are)
- make sure you have included the javascript files within your application.js file (your manifest file). The docs for bootstrap here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar say that you need to have the dropdown JS file included to make the dropdown work properly.

Please let me know if any of this helps.

Comment: thanks, I did not include the javascript files with in my application.js.